# can we consume WSRP portlet on J2EE application?

Tags: portlet, websphere-portal, wsrp

how to create a client for portlet as webservice in WSRP. i.e portlet is exposed as webservice and can we create a client for that service and consume it in J2EE application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WSRP is of version 2.0 then Service URL will be http://wportal8.cmp.com:10039/wps/wsdl/service.wsdl?version=v2. With the help of this URL you can generate clients but it is not possible to access portlet content wih the help of generated clients because Web service WSDL specifications and WSRP specifications are totally different.In WSDL communication is through SOAP where as in WSRP it is presentation layer.Alternate way is POC (Piece of Content URL) using this we will get atom feeds by parsing we can retrieve Portlet content.